# string in a sequence in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am solving a problem in codechef which is

> Chef has a sequence of N numbers. He like a sequence better if the sequence contains his favorite sequence as a substring.
>   Given the sequence and his favorite sequence(F) check whether the favorite sequence is contained in the sequence
>
> Input
>
> The first line will contain the number of test cases and are followed
>   by the cases.  Each test case consists of four lines: The length of
>   the sequence, the sequence N,the length of F and the sequence F
>
> Output
>
> Print "Yes" if the sequence contains the favourite sequence int it
>   otherwise print "No" Constraints

```
1<=T<=10 
    1 1
    Input:
    2
    6
    1 2 3 4 5 6
    3
    2 3 4
    6
    22 5 6 33 1 4
    2
    4 15


    Output:
    Yes
    No
```

to this I wrote 
`

```
for _ in xrange(int(raw_input())):
    raw_input()
    s = raw_input()
    raw_input()
    f =  raw_input()
    print "Yes" if f in s else "No"`
```

it returns correct result  (as far as I have checked ) bu the grader returns wrong. why is this wrong ?

Comment: Why do you call `raw_input()` without assigning anything to it?  Twice you call `raw_input()` with no apparent purpose.

Comment: @zondo thats how the codechef takes input and there is no need for the length of string in my code as you can read from the question statement  `The length of the sequence,the sequence N etc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine a scenario where the sequence is `'12 3 4'` and the subsequence is `'2 3 4'`. Your code will return `True` since `'2 3 4' in '12 3 4'` is `True`. You need to convert the sequence and subsequence to integers before doing the comparison.

Comment: ya you are right infact i wrote another code which passed the test but could not understand what happened to this one thanks to you now I know why thanks